# How to run code coverage for client side javascript code using grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, code-coverage, client-side, mocha-phantomjs

How can I run code coverage for client side javascript code using grunt?

I have run the client side javascript code test using mocha-phantomjs to be tested using html page, and it works fine, but I couldn't find a way to run code coverage for it.

It will be great if there is some sample code.

Comment: add 'grunt' tag to your question - it may help getting the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found away to do it using **mocha** **phantomjs** **istanbul** and **browserify** through grun.

In the client JS source code, make sure to expose your public var(s) or function(s) though window object, to make it accessible after generating the instrumentation file by browserify.
here is an example: https://github.com/shadiabuhilal/js-code-coverage-example/blob/master/src/example.js#L36

**devDependencies:**

```
"browserify-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"chai": "^1.10.0",
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-browserify": "^3.7.0",
"grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
"grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
"grunt-mocha-phantom-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"mocha": "^2.1.0"
```

To see full example please check the following repo:

https://github.com/shadiabuhilal/js-code-coverage-example